# Setting Color and Radius of a Circle in Java with Mutators and Accessors

Tags: java, bluej, accessor, mutators

I'm trying to write a program that states the color and area of a circle using String color and int radius using sets and gets. Using green & 10 as an example. Here's what I have so far:

---

```
public class Circle
{
    private String color;
    private int radius;

    public Circle () {
       color = "null";
       radius = 0;
    }

    public Circle (String setColor, int setRadius) {

    }

    public void setRadius (int radius) {
       this.radius = radius;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
       this.color = color;
    }

    public int getRadius(){
       return radius;
    }
    public String getColor(){
       return color;
    }

    public void printInfo(String setColor, int setRadius) {
       double area = Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
       System.out.printf("The " + "%s" + " circle has area " + "%.2f", 
       this.radius, area);
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

        Circle circle = new Circle("green", 10);

        circle.printInfo();
    }
}
```

"circle.printInfo();" has an error and I'm not sure why. Still pretty new to this so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor which takes arguments, you forgot to include code which defines the Circle. Right now, you create a circle with undefined variable, even though you passed it information. How to fix:

```
public Circle (String color, int radius) {
   this.setRadius(radius);
   this.setColor(color);
}
```

I believe you thought the arguments in the constructor took the place of the methods you created, but you are creating and defining local variables with the same name as the methods instead.

Hope this helps! Comment on anything that confuses you.